What should be the key for getting public_ip_id using boto3 ? key error on AllocationId
public_ip_id = instance.network_interfaces_attribute[0]['Association']['AllocationId']


KeyError: 'AllocationId'

If not AllocationId then what should be the correct attribute?

All 3 methods print the same IP address (although results will differ if you have multiple Network Interfaces):
import boto3

ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')
instance = ec2_resource.Instance('i-0e5bcb595a576c9e9')

print(instance.public_ip_address)

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
instance = ec2_client.describe_instances(InstanceIds=['i-0e5bcb595a576c9e9'])

print(instance['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['PublicIpAddress'])
print(instance['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['NetworkInterfaces'][0]['Association']['PublicIp'])


#1 worked for me - instance.public_ip_address
